# python container keeps trying to connect to mongo container via localhost

Tags: python, mongodb, docker

I am going to lose my mind because I've been stuck on this for 2 days and can't figure out why python wants to keep using 127.0.0.1 instead of the host I have specified. My docker compose snippet is:

```
# Use root/example as user/password credentials
version: '3.1'


services:
  mongo_service:
    image: mongo
    #command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    command: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'

      
  cinemas_api:
    container_name: cinemas_api
    hostname: cinemas_api
    build:
      context: ./cinemas_api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    links:
      - mongo_service
    ports:
     - 5000:5000
    expose:
     - '5000'
    depends_on:
      - mongo_service
  
  booking_api:
    container_name: booking_api
    hostname: booking_api
    build:
      context: ./booking_api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
     - 5050:5000
    depends_on:
      - mongo_service

networks:
  db_net:
    external: true



#docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml up --build
```

then in cinemas.py, I try to connect:

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb://mongo_service:27017/test')
```

However, I get the error

Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 ::
caused by :: Connection refused :

Comment: Is the mongod in the container set up as a replica set?

Comment: Has it ever been 127.0.0.1 in cinemas.py and then changed to point to the `mongo_service`?

Comment: Sorry, I’m not sure what you mean by replica. I never set it to 127.0.0.1 in cinemas.py and then changed it. It’s always been as is

Comment: In fact, you set the `27017:27017` as the mongo's port hence it would be accessible on `127.0.0.1:27017` either. Try to set static IP on the docker-compose services and try again. 
In my opinion, it's not an issue with your docker configs, focus on your code, though.

Comment: You missing some variable on Mongo_Config file.  Need Mongo_Service start-stop app on your system. Did you sure Mongo is an service and runnin on your system ?

Comment: Want to show the dockerfile for the cinemas or better yet upload this project to GitHub so we can all take a look?